# Having http error 500 in checkout success page of opencart

Tags: php, apache, opencart, httpserver

I am having HTTP server error 500 in the **checkout/success** page of my opencart website. I am trying to incorporate  the customised shipping integration code in the controller file **checkout/success.php** Where in I need to save couple of xml files on the server just after the order placed successfully. 
Is there any settings in the opencart which prevents opencart to work with XML? 
I am not able to find because no error except 500. I am using opencart 2.0.1.0 version.

I really need to resolve this issue soon. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I have used Opencart a few times in the past including development. Usually when I get an Error 500 I check the Error Logs on my server. Have you done this? It can give you some indication of what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Matt is right here. The first thing to do when debugging 500 Server Errors in OpenCart is to **look into your server's error log and find the exact error message**.

If there aren't any, you may need to enable them explicitly by adjusting the **error_reporting**, **display_errors** and **log_errors** settings in your PHP configuration. You can also temporarily change them in your main index.php file directly.

Once you know the exact error message, fixing it is a simple process.

We've covered some of the most common OpenCart error messages causing 500 Server Errors in our blog post: [Server Errors and Blank Pages in OpenCart: Most Common Causes](https://multimerch.com/blog/blank-pages-in-opencart-most-common-causes/).

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I already sorted out this error. But the blog you have shared will definitely help me in future. Thanks.